# Split string by position and numeric value in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, stringr

I'm attempting read in another group's data and there's one column where a pair of two numbers is usually separated by a comma, but in ~10% of cases (>15,000) there is no comma. It's too many to separate by hand, but I'm having trouble devising an efficient way to separate the string efficiently. Here are the rules:

1. string will be 5 or 6 characters, corresponding to two numbers that are each 2 or 3 characters
2. total if you add the two numbers will be roughly 150 to 250
3. maximum of either side will be 150
4. individual values should be maximized together, e.g. id = 8 would be 101 and 48 NOT 10 and 148, and if there's a tie, pick the pair with the largest small value, e.g. 11121 should be 111 and 21 NOT 11 and 121

Here's a sample:

```
tribble(
  ~id, ~to_split,
  1,   33118,
  2,   37118,
  3,   30121,
  4,   41110,
  5,   98121,
  6,   101102,
  7,   101110,
  8,   10148,
  9,   11121
) %>% 
  mutate_at("to_split", as.character)
```

And here's the result I'd like to get out:

```
tribble(
  ~id, ~left, ~right,
  1,   33, 118,
  2,   37, 118,
  3,   30, 121,
  4,   41, 110,
  5,   98, 121,
  6,   101, 102,
  7,   101, 110,
  8,   101, 48,
  9,   111, 21
)
```

I've thought about just splitting them into two different pairings by taking the first two characters and the remainder and the first three and the remainder and then adding those two pairings to see which total is the smallest. While I think this heuristic would work for everything, it's kind of a pain to implement. I'm thinking here of making two `separate` calls (with keep = TRUE), then presumably `pivot_long` and `group_by` id in order to `filter` the right option. Are there simpler options?

Ideally, I'd like to do this all in a mutate (possibly requiring `purrr::map`?) but I'm not sure how to split a string by position AND get both parts of it (without `separate`). If that is possible, it should be a simple matter of a `case_when`/`ifelse` to determine which pairing is smaller and then adding in a comma or other separator between them at the right position so I can `bind_rows` back to the rest of the table where I'll `separate` everything. But the only way I've found to separate a string and get both parts is to `separate`. Will something from `stringr` or `stringi` do this?

Comment: Can you pls explain the logic for id 9, picking 111 + 21 instead of 11 + 121?

Comment: Yeah, that's a weird edge case that honestly could be either one and I have no way of knowing given that I'm trying to figure out this group's rules around these numbers from the data and knowledge of the field. It's "better" to have the highest individual numbers that otherwise meet the rules given what they represent so picking 21 is better than the 11 (though there's a 11105 so 11s must be possible since 05 is weird and worse). If that's not clearly enough a part of four, lmk and I'll try and phrase it better.

Comment: Following up with this because I got a badge and because I got access to the original data that qas properly separated, this is the length of the match on either sides, as I suspected. You need a minimum match to meet the threshold for inclusion in such results, and usually in our field that's ~20. Hopefully that's .more satisfying. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a verbose approach that might be helpful as you refine for edge cases.

```
library(tidyverse)

# combine splits @ 2 and @ 3
bind_rows(df1 %>% mutate(split_pos = 2),
          df1 %>% mutate(split_pos = 3)) %>%
  
# calc features
  mutate(num1 = str_sub(to_split,   end = split_pos)     %>% parse_number(),
         num2 = str_sub(to_split, start = split_pos + 1) %>% parse_number(),
         total = num1 + num2,
         max = pmax(num1, num2)) %>%
  
# filter and pick best fit
  filter(total %>% between(100, 250), max <= 150) %>%
  arrange(id) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice_min(max) %>%
  ungroup()



    id to_split split_pos  num1  num2 total   max
  <dbl> <chr>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 33118            2    33   118   151   118
2     2 37118            2    37   118   155   118
3     3 30121            2    30   121   151   121
4     4 41110            2    41   110   151   110
5     5 98121            2    98   121   219   121
6     6 101102           3   101   102   203   102
7     7 101110           3   101   110   211   110
8     8 10148            3   101    48   149   101
9     9 11121            3   111    21   132   111
```

Answer (score 1):

This works on example dataset:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(cut = if_else(as.numeric(substr(to_split,1,3))<=150,3L,2L),
              length = nchar(to_split)) %>%
       mutate(left  = substr(to_split,1,cut),
              right = substr(to_split,cut+1,length)) %>%
       select(-cut,-length)

# A tibble: 8 x 4
     id to_split left  right
  <dbl> <chr>    <chr> <chr>
1     1 33118    33    118  
2     2 37118    37    118  
3     3 30121    30    121  
4     4 41110    41    110  
5     5 98121    98    121  
6     6 101102   101   102  
7     7 101110   101   110  
8     8 10148    101   48
```